# Images with .jpg not showing up on IPhone 5 Device

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, web-services

I'm retrieving my image via a web service. This web service gives me an URL which I convert to an image with a few lines of code. For some reason, all the images are displayed nicely on the simulator, but images do NOT show up on the device. I tried hard coding in a .png image and it showed up fine on the device. It seems as though all images on the device will NOT show up unless they are .png. Here is my code for converting the URL into an image:

```
NSString *imgurlString = bestPageDictionary[@"image_url"];
            NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imgurlString];
            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
            UIImage *imageForCell = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            [dVC setItemDisplayImage:imageForCell];
```

When I NSLog the URL string, I get this as a response: (for one of the items)

http://www.image-tmart.com/prodimgs/8/87004392/X039-Smart-Cover-PU-Leather-Protection-Case-for-iPad-2-The-New-iPad-3-iPad-4-Black_650x650.jpg

^ This image is rendering in the simulator, but not the device.

All help is appreciated, thanks in advance

EDIT: These images are not showing up on my iPhone 5 device

Comment: Which device are you running it on? I'm getting the image to open on my 4s

Comment: It's not running on the iPhone 5

Comment: I tested on my iPhone5s with the URL you gave. It worked very well.

Comment: Here's the code I tested. It's same as yours     UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.image-tmart.com/prodimgs/8/87004392/X039-Smart-Cover-PU-Leather-Protection-Case-for-iPad-2-The-New-iPad-3-iPad-4-Black_650x650.jpg"]];
    UIImage *image_ = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    [imageView setImage:image_];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

Comment: Yes. it worked. Is you network too slow? There're delegate methods for NSData receiving. Try to check the status.

Answer (score 0):

Check the exact extension of your picture,

in the simulator, it appears that `my_pic.jpg` and `my_pic.JPG` are similar, while in a real device.